# WFLYEJB0467: The request was rejected as the container is suspended

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, wildfly

When I am starting/restarting Wildfly 21 server, I am getting the following error

```
05:18:12,412 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 96) javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup mss-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT/ejbModule-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT/CompleteCallSessionBean!com.xim.mss.ejb.sessionbeans.completecall.CompleteCallRemoteInterface [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: **org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.EJBComponentUnavailableException: WFLYEJB0467: The request was rejected as the container is suspended**]
```

But I am not getting this error when I am deploying the EAR ?
Can anyone tell me why this is happening?
Is this expected error or does this need to be resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected error, you are performing an EJB call before the EJB container is started and it is in suspended state (I reproduced the issue with a similar situation).

I have found a similar explanation for the error when the server is in shutdown (when the EJB container is also suspended).

https://issues.redhat.com/browse/JBEAP-444

The best solution is to delay this ejb call with a timer to wait the application to be fully started.